# How to make only traffic from some APPs go through VPN in Android?

Tags: android

I want to build a VPN APP on Android basing VPN service. one special requirement of this VPN APP is it has a white list, only traffic come from APPs in this list will go to VPN server. All rest traffic go to what they used to go.

For example, I have a VPN server in USA, and I am in China. I want Facebook goes through VPN. but Youku goes to Youku's server directly.

My first problem here is how can determine some traffic come from which APP?

I know it's possible, because there an APP called no root firewall can block traffic per APP, which is also basing Android VPN service.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.firewall

I'm new to Android, can anybody tell me how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I also want to achieve the same goal, @Daniel do you get anything helpful uptill now?

Comment: unfortunately, I haven't got anything useful, and I have stop my research on such thing, I'm focusing on Django development recently.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [addAllowedApplication()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.Builder.html#addAllowedApplication(java.lang.String)) method, it accepts the packageName who's traffic should be allowed to go through VpnService.